# Drupal Table of form elements

Tags: php, forms, drupal-7

I am trying to create a table in the config page for my module. I need the table to include some form elements, Checkbox and textfield. I want to structure the table like so.

Enable | Name | Int

Enable being the checkbox, name being a standard text value and int being the textfield. I want to be able to check a box next to a name, type in a value and then have it save when it submits. Currently I am doing this in the .admin.inc. I have actually been able to make the table and have the elements in it. However I cant put values in or get them out.

How I am creating the rows

```
  foreach($rows as  $row){

  $form['table']['intvalue'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => 100,
      '#size' => 8,      
  );
  $form['table']['enable'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#default_value' => TRUE,   
  );
  $rows[] = array(drupal_render($form['table']['enable']), $name, drupal_render($form['table']['intvalue']));
  }
```

And this is how I am displaying the table

```
 $table = theme('table', array(
    'header' => $header,
    'rows' => $rows,
    'id' => 'table-articles',
    'class' => 'articles',
  ));
  $form['table'] = array(

  '#type' => 'item',
  '#title' => t('Table'),
  '#markup' => $table,
  '#weight' => -2,
  );
```

Any idea?